# memchr in fgets call coredump in libc-2.22

Tags: glibc, fgets, libc

stack like this：

> #0 0x7fc5e7530f50 in memchr() from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #1 0x7fc5e7516f67 in __GI__IO_getline_info() from /lib64/libc.so.6
> #2 0x7fc5e7514f44 in fgets () from /lib64/libc.so.6

we check the libc code and the stream:

```
if ((_IO_size_t) len >= n)
len = n;
t = (char *) memchr ((void *) fp->_IO_read_ptr, delim, len);
if (t != NULL)
```

and check the fp：

(gdb) p *(FILE *)0x11a2090
$5 = {_flags = -72538999,
_IO_read_ptr = 0x7ffd239f53a1 "LTER FOREIGN TABLE dbbackup.dwpdata_t00_pbc_admin_encourage_info OWNER TO mppedw;\n\n--\n-- Name: dwpdata_t00_pbc_crdt_apprv_qry_rec_dtl; Type: FOREIGN TABLE; Schema: dbbackup; Owner: mppedw; Tablespace:"..., _IO_read_end = 0x7ffd239f739f "",
_IO_read_base = 0x7ffd239f53a0 "ALTER FOREIGN TABLE dbbackup.dwpdata_t00_pbc_admin_encourage_info OWNER TO mppedw;\n\n--\n-- Name: dwpdata_t00_pbc_crdt_apprv_qry_rec_dtl; Type: FOREIGN TABLE; Schema: dbbackup; Owner: mppedw; Tablespace"...,
_IO_write_base = 0x7ffd239f53a0 "ALTER FOREIGN TABLE dbbackup.dwpdata_t00_pbc_admin_encourage_info OWNER TO mppedw;\n\n--\n-- Name: dwpdata_t00_pbc_crdt_apprv_qry_rec_dtl; Type: FOREIGN TABLE; Schema: dbbackup; Owner: mppedw; Tablespace"...,
_IO_write_ptr = 0x7ffd239f53a0 "ALTER FOREIGN TABLE dbbackup.dwpdata_t00_pbc_admin_encourage_info OWNER TO mppedw;\n\n--\n-- Name: dwpdata_t00_pbc_crdt_apprv_qry_rec_dtl; Type: FOREIGN TABLE; Schema: dbbackup; Owner: mppedw; Tablespace"...,
_IO_write_end = 0x7ffd239f53a0 "ALTER FOREIGN TABLE dbbackup.dwpdata_t00_pbc_admin_encourage_info OWNER TO mppedw;\n\n--\n-- Name: dwpdata_t00_pbc_crdt_apprv_qry_rec_dtl; Type: FOREIGN TABLE; Schema: dbbackup; Owner: mppedw; Tablespace"...,
_IO_buf_base = 0x7ffd239f53a0 "ALTER FOREIGN TABLE dbbackup.dwpdata_t00_pbc_admin_encourage_info OWNER TO mppedw;\n\n--\n-- Name: dwpdata_t00_pbc_crdt_apprv_qry_rec_dtl; Type: FOREIGN TABLE; Schema: dbbackup; Owner: mppedw; Tablespace"..., _IO_buf_end = 0x7ffd239f739f "", _IO_save_base = 0x0, _IO_backup_base = 0x0, _IO_save_end = 0x0, _markers = 0x0,
_chain = 0x7fc5e784b080 <*IO_2_1_stderr*>, _fileno = 5, _flags2 = 0, _old_offset = 0, _cur_column = 0, _vtable_offset = 65 'A', _shortbuf = "", _lock = 0x11a2170, _offset = -1,
__pad1 = 0x0, __pad2 = 0x11a2180, __pad3 = 0x0, __pad4 = 0x0, __pad5 = 0, _mode = -1, _unused2 = "\a\a\000\000\261\036\000\000\000\000\000\000\230\246\204\347\305\177\000"}

found nothing can generate the core

and the core in dmesg like this：

segfault at 0x7fc5e7530f50 ip 00007fc5e7530f50 sp 00007ffd239f5238 error 15 in libc-2.22.so[0x7fc5e74ab000+0x19b000]

and then we check the disassemble and found

==> 0x7fc5e7530f50  :       movq %rsi,%xmm1

and the info registor is :

> rax            0x41    65
> rbx            0x75bc71    7715953
> rcx            0x7fc5e758b320  140487966634784
> rdx            0x3fe   1022
> rsi            0xa 10
> rdi            0x7ffd239f53a1  140725201097633
> rbp            0xa 0xa
> rsp            0x7ffd239f5238  0x7ffd239f5238
> r8             0x1 1
> r9             0x0 0
> r10            0x3fe   1022
> r11            0x246   582
> r12            0x3fe   1022
> r13            0x7ffd239f53a1  140725201097633
> r14            0x11a2090   18489488
> r15            0x3fe   1022
> rip            0x7fc5e7530f50  0x7fc5e7530f50 
> eflags         0x10206 [ PF IF RF ]
> cs             0x33    51
> ss             0x2b    43
> ds             0x0 0
> es             0x0 0
> fs             0x0 0
> gs             0x0 0

what is happened in glibc, this is very very strange.

Comment: The code example is mostly incomplete, so it's hard to tell what really is the problem.

Comment: I've pasted the code, please check, tks

Comment: I wasn't talking about the glibc code, but about your code: Or are you saying that glbc code is not correct? Maybe show an example that triggers the problem in glibc. And why did you put glibc code into an answer? Edit you question instead!